# requests in python get error WSAECONNRESET

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, oserror

I'm trying to get exchange rate with a request:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml?curr=01')
```

I'm getting an error :
{ConnectionError}('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')"))

What is the solution for that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server does a check for valid/supported browsers. You need to pass one it accepts e.g.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml?curr=01', headers=headers)
```